# Is there a systematic way to derive constraint equations?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, constrained-dynamics

There's this problem in Goldstein's (Classical Mechanics) derivations section:

> 5. Two wheels of radius $a$ are mounted on the ends of a common axle of length $b$ such that the wheels rotate independently. The whole combination rolls without slipping on a plane. Show that there are two nonholonomic equations of constraint,
>
> $$\begin{align}
> \cos\theta dx + \sin\theta dy &= 0 \\
> \sin\theta dx - \cos\theta dy &= \frac{1}{2}a(d\phi + d\phi'),
> \end{align}$$
>
> (where $\theta$, $\phi$, and $\phi'$ have meanings similar to those in the problem of a single vertical disk, and $(x,y)$ are the coordinates of a point on the axle midway between the two wheels) and one holonomic equation of constraint,
>
> $$\theta = C - \frac{a}{b}(\phi - \phi'),$$
>
> where $C$ is a constant.

And here's the image from the problem with a single vertical disk:

[image: image from problem with vertical disk]

Now, I believe I have successfully derived the equations for two of those constraints, but I'll write it anyway, in case my reasoning is somehow wrong or too sloppy. (I use the labels $1$ and $2$ for the wheels, instead of unprimed and primed.)

$$\dot{x} = v \sin{\theta}$$

$$\dot{y} = -v \cos{\theta}$$
$$\implies \color{red}{\cos{\theta} \, dx + \sin{\theta} \, dy = 0}$$
And the second one:
By rotating the wheels about the midpoint $(x,y)$, the angle $\theta$ changes such that $$d \theta = \frac{2}{b} \, dl$$ where $dl$ is the length of the arc swept by both wheels, satisfying $$dl = v_1 \, dt = - v_2 \, dt$$ because the wheels turn with anti-parallel velocities.
$$ dl = v_1 \, dt = a \frac{d \phi_1}{dt} \, dt = a \, d\phi_1$$
$$ dl = -v_2 \, dt = -a \frac{d \phi_2}{dt} \, dt = -a \, d\phi_2$$
$$\implies \color{red}{d\theta = -\frac{a}{b} (d \phi_1 - d \phi_2) },$$
which implies the holonomic constraint equation, with flipped signs. 
(I guess I just picked different labels, right?)

How can I get the last one? I don't have much experience with these sorts of problems, so I was wondering, **is there a systematic way to approach them** or is it always just hacking at the problem, hoping to pull out the constraint equations?

*P.S. My question got edited because of policy reasons according to which I cannot ask some questions, so I would like to say that I don't want to know if my reasoning is correct for the derivation of first two constraints.* :)

**EDIT, PLEASE READ:** 
Although I answered my own question regarding the specific problem mentioned here, if anyone provides a good answer regarding a systematic way to derive constraint equations, I will accept that answer instead.

Comment: The first of your three questions, and to some extent the second, are off topic under our [homework policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/714), but rather than put the question on hold I edited to cut it down to the underlying conceptual question.

Comment: I am grateful for your mercy, my lord, for I am a mere mortal, I shall not question thee.

Comment: lol ;-) seriously though, you can edit the question further if you want. Including rolling back my edit, if you really don't like it, but I think I would put the original version of the question on hold.

Comment: Exactly, what's the point?

Comment: @SchlomoSteinbergerstein: It seems like the main question you have is not "is my derivation correct?", but rather is the more broadly-applicable question "is there a systematic way to approach them or is it always just hacking at the problem, hoping to pull out the constraint equations?", ie, you're wondering if there exists an automatable procedure which can be applied to a broad class of problems, not just this one in particular. While I don't know the answer to that, I think you maybe could boldface the "**is there a systematic way**..." sentence to make it more prominent, or something.

Comment: @SchlomoSteinbergerstein: Broadly-applicable questions like that are typically well-liked here, and almost always are considered on-topic, since they have the potential to help a lot of people.

Comment: Oh to hell with your policy, what about thousands of other questions similar to this one? I could have as well asked my question implicitly... why does it matter if I state it explicitly for the sake of clarity?

And who's to say that an answer to this question wouldn't be broadly applicable, many answers of this kind helped me greatly, even if they weren't about a specific problem I was dealing with.

Do you really think that kind of policy is actually improving the quality of the website and helping everyone?

Comment: Also, I did ask "is there a systematic way...", but I just wanted someone to confirm my reasoning for the previous derivation, I could have as well asked later in the comments, what would the difference be? You guys are seriously overly pedantic, this is counter-productive and honestly, annoying, considering the fact that my question is pretty decent compared to many other questions that pass the wrath of moderators.

Comment: (Now just leave it and go moderate something worth moderating.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got it, I found a much better way to solve this problem, which eliminates my wish to confirm my previous reasoning and it partially answers the question the moderators' policy forced upon me, which was only a side-question to the main thing I wanted to ask, namely to help me solve this problem... That's why this answer might look like missing the point, but it isn't. Anyway, here's my answer:

The contact points of the wheels with the $xy$ plane have these coordinates for the *lower* **(1)** and the *upper* **(2)** wheel respectively:

$$(x_1,y_1) = \left(x-\frac{b}{2}\cos{\theta},\,  y - \frac{b}{2}\sin{\theta}\right)$$
$$(x_2,y_2) = \left(x+\frac{b}{2}\cos{\theta},\,  y + \frac{b}{2}\sin{\theta}\right)$$
Taking the time derivatives yields:
$$(\dot{x_1},\dot{y_1}) = \left(\dot{x}+\frac{b}{2}\dot{\theta}\sin{\theta}, \, y - \frac{b}{2}\dot{\theta}\cos{\theta}\right)$$
$$(\dot{x_2},\dot{y_2}) = \left(\dot{x}-\frac{b}{2}\dot{\theta}\sin{\theta}, \, y + \frac{b}{2}\dot{\theta}\cos{\theta}\right)$$
Also, we have these relations:
$$(\dot{x_1},\dot{y_1}) = (v_1 \sin{\theta}, -v_1 \cos{\theta}) = (a \dot{\phi_1} \sin{\theta}, -a \dot{\phi_1} \cos{\theta})$$
$$(\dot{x_2},\dot{y_2}) = (v_2 \sin{\theta}, -v_2 \cos{\theta}) = (a \dot{\phi_2} \sin{\theta}, -a \dot{\phi_2} \cos{\theta})$$
From there, eliminating $dt$ and performing simple algebraic manipulations gives:
$$dx = \sin{\theta}\left(-\frac{b}{2} d\theta + a \, d\phi_1\right)$$
$$dx = \sin{\theta}\left(\frac{b}{2} d\theta + a \, d\phi_2\right)$$
$$dy = -\cos{\theta}\left(-\frac{b}{2} d\theta + a \, d\phi_1\right)$$
$$dy = -\cos{\theta}\left(\frac{b}{2} d\theta + a \, d\phi_2\right)$$
Getting the final three equations of constraint is simply a matter of combining these, but if anyone wants it, I can write out the procedure explicitly.

Comment: Welcome to the world of kinematics. Here you parametrize a position coordinate and take derivatives to get to velocity and accelration relationships.

Comment: yeah, sometimes it's easy to miss the most obvious method xD